# Android - onCreate()

Tags: java, android, oop

Is there a way to access to variables on onCreate(), to reuse them in another class?

```
String testSubCa="";
String prixe="";
String testWiifi="";
Double testPrice=0.0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_srdata);
    testSubCa = getIntent().getStringExtra(SearchRestau.txxtSub);
    prixe = getIntent().getStringExtra(SearchRestau.txtprix);
    testWiifi =  getIntent().getStringExtra(SearchRestau.txxtWifi);
    testPrice=Double.parseDouble(prixe);
    refresh = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgRefresh);
    refresh.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

I need to use these data :/

Comment: This is not an android question, it is a basic class structuring/data access question.

Comment: @JoxTraex is right. Nevertheless define the variables as static: `public static String testSubCa="";`. If you named the class `SearchRestau`, it will work.

Comment: No changes... My class only accesses what's already initialized.

Comment: I'm using these entries with another data from my database.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't really specify what exactly your plan is, it's a bit of a challenge getting a proper solution.
I'm just going to assume what you want to do is to start an activity, let the user do something inside this activity and then go back to where it was started from with the ability to use the values created inside the activity.

The easiest way to that is by not starting the activity via startActivity(Intent) but rather by using `startActivityForResult(Intent, RequestCode);`

In the same activity you then need to handle the event of actually getting a result. To do this you need to implement the method

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        //Your code to retrieve the data here!
    }
}
```

The variables should be stored inside the Intent data and can be grabbed by using 
`data.getStringExtra();`

To place the values inside the result you need to place this code in the activity you actually create them:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("value_id", value);
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

I hope that helps with your problem!
GL